# Is the notation $f(x)$ "deprecated by professional mathematicians" (as claimed by Wolfram)?

Tags: tag-removed, notation

Wolfram's MathWorld website, at the page on [functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Function.html), makes the following claim about the notation $f(x)$ for a function:

> While this notation is deprecated by professional mathematicians, it is the more familiar one for most nonprofessionals.

From context, it appears that this is referring to the use of $f(x)$ to refer to *the actual function*, rather than just to a particular value, when $x$ is (in the context) a dummy variable.

Is this true?  Do professional mathematicians "deprecate" this notation?

To avoid long and windy discussions as to the values or otherwise of this notation (which would be much more appropriate in a blog), this question should be viewed as a poll.  As MO runs on StackExchange 1.0, it doesn't have the feature whereby the actual "up" and "down" votes for an answer can be easily seen.  Therefore I shall post two answers, one in favour and one against, the following statement.  Please **only vote up**.  A vote for one answer will be taken as a vote against the other.  The Law of the Excluded Middle does not hold here.  The motion is:

> This house believes that the notation $f(x)$ to refer to a function has value in professional mathematics and that there is no need to apologise or feel embarrassed when using it thus.

**This poll has now run its course. The final tally can be seen below.**

Comment: Take the advice on the Wolfram site with a dose of skepticism.  People write $x \longmapsto f(x)$ rather than simply writing $f(x)$ when one needs to make clear what the variable is -- for example try to walk through the proof that a finite-dimensional vector space is isomorphic to its double dual without using this notation and you'll see why people like it.  But it really only becomes important to make these distinctions when it's difficult to "identify" the variable in a functional expression.

Comment: I agree with Ryan.  That is a strange claim by Wolfram, especially the part about "most rigorous notation".  I should note that I've seen some CS-oriented people write $f = \lambda(x \mapsto x^2)$ instead of $f(x) = x^2$ or $f: x \mapsto x^2$.  As long as the reader can understand what is happening without ambiguity, I don't see a reason to impose a standard.

Comment: The question asked in the title is not the question asked in the body. Can you make up your mind as to what exactly you would like to know, and edit accordingly? 

Comment: "deprecated by professional mathematicians" - which ones, I wonder?

Comment: I don't think that this is a good question for MO. Then again, I don't feel sufficiently strongly to vote to close --- moreover, I don't have a great reason for feeling this way.  It's just that I think this would make a better discussion on a blog (or in a bar) than on MathOverflow (or in a mathematics seminar).

Comment: @Theo, it *might* make sense to keep this question open.  Although mathematicians may know when to trust the Wolfram site and when not to, I think the site has credibility in the general population as Wolfram is the producer of a popular mathematics software package.  So this thread would have something of an "outreach" role, at least as a rebuttal to the statement "depreciated by professional mathematicians".  This is definately a borderline question though so I have no strong feelings either way.

Comment: _As is_, the question is too vague.  There are three question marks denoting three distinct questions.  The actual questions are more suited to a blog post, I feel.  I have some sympathy with the "request to rescue" based on countering the disinformation but feel that the question needs rewording in order for it to fit that mode.  Given that it is borderline _as is_, I'm going to edit it to fit that.  Those with sufficient rep can, of course, edit it themselves or revert it if it's felt I've not done it correctly.

Comment: Okay, I've unilaterally turned this in to a "poll" question.  If someone wants to keelhaul me for doing so, please open a thread at meta to do so.

Comment: meta thread: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/692/poll-question-about-wolfram/ (please vote for this comment so that it appears "above the fold")

Comment: It's not a great question as formulated. A discussion of function notation with a free variable may or may not be something to deprecate, depending on how *x* is treated (*y* may be as good as *x* but equating f(x) = f(y) is in remarkably bad taste). With no reasons given, it is kind of hopeless. MathWorld will have had reasons, but how deep do they go? Serge Lang was influential with the barred short arrow, category theory is influential in elementless notation. Bound variable clash is an artefact of poorish notation. What are we talking here?

Comment: I think that there are certain cases involving morphisms depending on $n$ variables (and taking on different roles).  For example, it's hard to say certain things about $Hom$ without filling in variables (For instance, the definition of composition is $M_{XYZ}:Hom(X,Y)\times Hom(Y,Z)\to Hom(X,Z)$ seems like it would be very tough to write without plugging in. 

Comment: Harry: google for «the FP programming language».

Answer (score 52):

Vote for this answer if you **agree** with the statement:

> This house believes that the notation $f(x)$  to refer to a function has value in professional mathematics and that there is no need to apologise or feel embarrassed when using it thus.

(Note: the answer is CW so that this is a genuine poll)

Comment: It's just an abbreviation for λx.f(x)

Answer (score 32):

Vote for this answer if you **disagree** with the statement:

> This house believes that the notation $f(x)$  to refer to a function has value in professional mathematics and that there is no need to apologise or feel embarrassed when using it thus.

(Note: the answer is CW so that this is a genuine poll)

Comment: Andrew, at present this isn't CW.

Comment: Whoops!  Fixed.  As you can probably tell, I just cut-and-pasted from one to the other, but the CW bit doesn't get included.  I'll donate all the rep that I got to charity.  Oh, wait, no-one's voted for this yet so that's nothing.  (Seriously, I hope this _hasn't_ skewed the results)